# AWS Secrets Manager - use secrets in local Codebuild container

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I have database credentials stored in AWS Secrets Manager which I'd like to pull and set as environment variables in a localised Codebuild container. I am using the 4.0 Codebuild image and the codebuild_build.sh script to test Codebuild on my local machine.

Currently my buildspec.yml looks like this at the start:

```
version: 0.2

env:
    secrets-manager:
        DATABASE_USER: <secret_name>:<secret_key_for_database_user>
```

When I run the script I get this:

```
agent_1  | [Container] 2020/12/06 21:30:16 Phase context status code: Secrets Manager Error Message: ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
agent_1  | [Container] 2020/12/06 21:30:16 Runtime error (*clienterr.PhaseContextError: ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.)
```

I've tried obtaining the secret using the aws client and that works fine. I don't think it's an issue with my credentials because I get to this step when running the codebuild_build.sh script with the -c option and when hardcoding my aws secret key id and the secret key itself into the buildspec.yml. I have also tried using the full ARN of the secret but have had no luck.

Is there a trick that I'm missing here? Do I need to update the resource permissions on the secret itself inside the AWS Secrets Manager or on Codebuild, (both locally and on AWS)?

Comment: The error message means that `<secret_name>` is incorrect. Maybe your secret is in the wrong region or different account? Its not a permissions issue, as this would result in Access Deny errors.

Comment: I've definitely set correct the region in my local ~/.aws/config and I've also tried this by hardcoding the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` (as well as trying `AWS_REGION` ) inside `env: variables:` in the buildspec.yml. I'm certain the name is correct - and this also fails when I try to use the full ARN. Is there another way I should be setting the region when running the *codebuild_build.sh* script?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm running into it at the moment. If I figure it out I'll post an Answer but just wondering if you already solved it